# jQuery Sortable placeholder with destination size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jQuery Sortable plugin to display sortable images. And i want to have a diferente size only on the first position.

The problem is when i try to move a image **to** or **from** the first position, the placeholder always keep the size of the source image and not the target image.

I'm using the sortable plugin like this:

```
$(".dropzone-image-list").sortable({
      connectWith: ".dropzone-image-item-drag",
      handle: ".dropzone-image-item-drag",
      placeholder: "sortable-box-placeholder-image-list", 
      forcePlaceholderSize: true,
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      forceHelperSize: true,
      helper: 'original',
    });
```

If it helps to understand you can access the [jsfiddle.net/5ke2g740/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/5ke2g740/1/)